# Send test mail functionality not working nopCommerce 3.40

Tags: email, smtp, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce3.40

I've try to sent test mail but its return error.

my setting

```
Email Address: abcd@gmail.com
Display Name : abcd
Host         : smtp.gmail.com
Port         : 587
User Name    : abcd@gmail.com
Password     : *******
Enable SSL   : True
UseDefaultCre: False
```

and send test email to : `wxyz@yahoo.com.au`

return error:

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
```

Answer (score 0):

Does setting the port to 465 work?

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en